# Implementing usernames to devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have followed the documentation online, however I am still struggling and I don't know where I went wrong. When I am trying to sign a user up, all I am seeing is 'please review the problems below' upon them submitting, which isn't even being displayed.The terminal also isn't saying much.

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: [:username, :password]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: [:username, :password]
  end


end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_many :stories
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false}
  validates_format_of :username, with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$/, :multiline => true
  attr_accessor :login
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => {email: true, login: false}

 def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions.to_h).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      elsif conditions.has_key?(:username) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
        where(conditions.to_h).first
      end
    end

end
```

In the terminal:

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sTFYfOW5txc1AYinMyWDdaMfggAGh1oX/JSrR7vXc25cEwW5krezOQ6V5zE6QLXI6Dmwi8X3LN8s91rahJBxww==", "user"=>{"username"=>"indigo", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER(?) LIMIT ?  [["username", "indigo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering users/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/shared/_links.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered users/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.7ms)
/home/benjamin/Desktop/projectoxygen/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:47: warning: else without rescue is useless
Completed 200 OK in 306ms (Views: 42.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

devise db file:

```
 class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
      def change
        create_table :users do |t|
          ## Database authenticatable
          t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
          t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

          ## Recoverable
          t.string   :reset_password_token
          t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

          ## Rememberable
          t.datetime :remember_created_at

          ## Trackable
          t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
          t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
          t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
          t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
          t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

          ## Confirmable
          # t.string   :confirmation_token
          # t.datetime :confirmed_at
          # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
          # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

          ## Lockable
          # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
          # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
          # t.datetime :locked_at


          t.timestamps null: false
        end

        add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
        add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true

        change_column :users, :email, uniqueness: false

        # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
        # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
      end
    end
```

current errors:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

terminal:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Terminal shows the error: `User Exists`, try with unique username!

Comment: Sorry, must of done a re-type. I have posted the new terminal error above. I entered new details on the sign up.

Comment: If you want to have a username-based sign up / login, every usernames need to be unique across your database.

Comment: class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string
    add_index :users, :username, unique: true
  end
end

Comment: @Benjamints you need to add `def email_required?; false; end` method to your model, in order to avoid validation for email.

Comment: I have, thank you dkp but it has given me a new error below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `username` instead of `email` as authentication key, then you must have defined:

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
config.authentication_keys = [:username]
```

-
OR, you can define authentication key in model also as:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :authentication_keys => [:username]
```

Add the following methods to model **User** in order to avoid validations for email:

```
def email_required?
  false
end

def email_changed?
  false
end
```

If you have a UNIQUE constraint over the email column, then create a migration to remove index on email column:

```
def change
  remove_index :users, :email
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I added your code and the error has gone away but produced a new one. SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Comment: I have :validatable, in my user.rb and it still comes up with the error above.

Comment: @Benjamints The problem is that you have UNIQUE constraint over the email column in db, you can change that with a migration. Just create a migration: `column: change_column :users, :email, uniqueness: false`

Comment: I am really sorry I am new to rails and I don't understand how to achieve this. I really appreciate your help. All the devise code is completely off my level but I need this authentication.

Comment: @Benjamints Please check my above comment and try to add a migration to remove `uniqueness` constraint.

Comment: Hi dkp, sorry for the late response.  do I do this in the terminal by running a 'rails g migration' or manually add this in the devise DB file and save it?

Many thanks,

Ben.

Comment: I have added the devise db file if you need to have a look.

Comment: @Benjamints create a new migration file from your terminal like:  `rails g migration RemoveEmailUniquenessFromUser` , then go to: `app/db/migrate` , open the last migration file and add this line inside it `change_column :users, :email, uniqueness: false`  and run your migration using `rake db:migrate`

Comment: That makes much more sense to me now :) Thank you. Unfortunately, rake db:migrate gave me an error 'undefined method `to_sym' for {:uniqueness=>false}:Hash'

Comment: Thank you for your response. Appreciate it. Unfortunately it still gives me the errors. I have edit my post at the bottom to post them.

Comment: Is there any other part of my application you would like to see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129533/discussion-between-dkp-and-benjamints).

Comment: No problem ..:)